# Re-ordering items in a HStack

Tags: swiftui, hstack

Is it possible to re-order buttons inside a Hstack? i want to be able to click and drag any of the buttons from right to left, vice versa but not sure how to do it. This is for a macOS app.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Button("1") {
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            
            Button("2") {
            }
            .padding()
            
            
            Button("3") {
            }
            .padding()
            
            
    
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can do that with DragGesture: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/draggesture